# Implement Backspace for CalculatorBrain for Stanford CS193P

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I'm looking to implement the backspace functionality for the calculator project.

I can add an action with code below to the viewcontroller to deal with it, but shouldn't it really be placed in the CalcModel.

```
[self secureSetDisplayText:([self.display.text substringToIndex:([self.display.text length]-1)])];
```

So if the CalcModel is to be reused in a different project the backspace is implemented already!

Any thoughts

Comment: so your question exactly is...

Comment: should I implement the backspace method in the calcmodel or in the view controller?

Comment: I think your question is more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

No, it should be in the ViewController. The model would then have to communicate the change to the ViewController instead of the Controller passing the information to the model. Also the modal is only aware of what is passed to it from the ViewController so the Controller can decide not to pass a number to it. (press 45, remove the 5 press enter. The modal does not know the 5 ever existed because the number never got past the view until a control (in the controller) was activated).

Comment: Ok, I understand your thinking behind this, but if I want to reuse the CalcModel elsewhere it means I am duplicating the validation functionality, hence I think it should be in the CalcModel.

Comment: What does the validation functionality have to do with the backspace button? One checks to see if the input is valid and the other just changes the input right? Those are two entirely different things.

Comment: If I put the validation in the viewcontroller then I must duplicate the validation code everywhere I need to use the CalcModel. Also as each digit is pressed it gets passsed to the CalcModel anyway.

Comment: Every time you press a digit it gets passed to the model? See that does not make sense to me. I would only pass it to the model when a whole number is entered (so the backspace would end up in the viewcontroller). Otherwise the CalcModel needs to handle putting all consecutive numbers together. The validate information I would put in the CalcModel.